# VB.NET XML Literal Variable Element Name with Namespace

Tags: xml, vb.net

How do I have a variable element name when using XML literals? It's fine when I don't try to use a namespace but when I do, it fails.

This works fine:

```
Dim elementName As String = "tc" 
Dim tc As XElement = <<%= elementName %>/>
```

and returns:

```
<tc />
```

But if I try to add the 'w:' namespace then it doesn't:

```
Dim tc As XElement = <w:<%= elementName %>/>
```

Or this:

```
Dim tc As XElement = <<%= "w:" & elementName %>/>
```

So can anyone tell me how to get to:

```
<w:tc />
```

variably, using xml literals?

**UPDATE:**

Thank you martin for your answer, that was just what I was looking for. Just to clarify, the root document I was working on already had the namespace I needed, I am just adding to / editing an existing document (a wordprocessingml document).

I think, this was the simplest and most elegant way to solve this:

```
Dim tc as XElement = <<%= Me.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("w") + elementName %>/>
```

Where `Me` is a class that inherits XDocument.

Comment: Although accepted, this is not how XML is expected to be dealt with in .NET (= you are not maximising the huge OO-capabilities). You should better rely on the adequate classes/properties. For example:  Dim tc As XElement = New XElement(elementName); or use the XNamespace class for namespaces.

Comment: Well then what's the point in the XML literal syntax if I can't even add a namespace?

Comment: you need to add the uri not the namespace code, ie "uri:my-uri" & elementName

Comment: I am not saying that you cannot add a namespace (or any other thing) via literals; I am saying that you are not maximising the available power.

Comment: How am I not maximising the available power varocarbas? Can you show me a simpler, more elegant way to do this in the same number of lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an expression that constructs an `XName` (doing `XNamespace + "localName"`) e.g.

```
    Dim ns1 As XNamespace = "http://example.com/ns1"
    Dim ns2 As XNamespace = "http://example.com/ns2"
    Dim localName1 As String = "foo"
    Dim localName2 As String = "bar"
    Dim root As XElement =
    <root xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns1" xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/ns2">
        <<%= ns1 + localName1 %>>test</>
        <<%= ns2 + localName1 %>>test 2</>
        <<%= ns1 + localName2 %>>test</>
        <<%= ns2 + localName2 %>>test 2</>
    </root>
    Console.WriteLine(root)
```

Result is

```
<root xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns1" xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/ns2">
  <ns1:foo>test</ns1:foo>
  <ns2:foo>test 2</ns2:foo>
  <ns1:bar>test</ns1:bar>
  <ns2:bar>test 2</ns2:bar>
</root>
```

Comment: Thankyou martin, I went a little simpler as I was already adding xml to a document with namespaces referenced, so I used Me.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("w") + localName1 for example. I will update my answer with this.